# How to make a bot edit its message in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I've tried looking at other solutions but they havent worked for me. What im trying to do is make the bot edit its own message at a slight delay.

```
  if message.content.startswith('(dev)messageedit'):
    await message.channel.send('old message')
    time.sleep(1)
    await message.edit('new message')
```

The error im getting is:

```
TypeError: edit() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

It would be great if you could help me!